# Set Jquery tabs after content in showcase has been render

Tags: jquery, tabs, load

This dumb thing is driven me crazy

I want to set a responsive teaser(showbiz pro) that displays a showcase to work with tabs, so ii the user select tab 2 it will show inside the container of the showcase items 2.

The problem is that the showcase script set some values to de elements in the container at while the page is been render, but when is in "display: none" couse of the tabs system, dosent set does values. I have tried many solutions and im stuck.

```
 jQuery('#products-tipo-2').showbizpro({
          dragAndScroll:"off",
          carousel:"off",
          allEntryAtOnce:"off",
          visibleElementsArray:[4,4,4,1],
          mediaMaxHeight:[0,0,0,0],
          entrySizeOffset:0
      });                   

                // TABS

        $("ul#nav-tabs-1").tabs("div#joder > div");
```

I need that the tabs to be trigger after the first block its completed. I tried to make it a callback, and other things. Please help. Thanx

```
enter code here
```